# cannot update data in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter

I can't update my data in database. Here is my code:

controller :

```
public function update_contact()
{
    sleep(1);
    $data['validation_error'] = '';
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[40]|callback_alpha_dash_space');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[40]|valid_email');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required|max_length[15]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbo_list', 'Group Name', 'required');

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
        $message = "<strong>Editing</strong> failed!";
        $this -> json_response(FALSE, $message);
    } 
    else {
        $this -> contact_model -> update($this -> input -> post('name'), $this -> input -> post('email'), $this -> input -> post('phone'), $this -> input -> post('cbo_list'), $this -> session -> userdata('uid'));
        $message = "<strong>" . $this -> input -> post('name') . "</strong> has been edited!";
        $this -> json_response(TRUE, $message);
        redirect("site/contacts"); 
    } 
}
```

and this is my model :

```
public function update($cid, $name, $email, $phone, $cbo_list)
{
    $this->db->where(array('uid' => $this -> session -> userdata('uid'), 'cid' => $cid))
        ->update('contacts', array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'gid' => $cbo_list));          
}
```

> for addition info :
>
> my cont s name = site,
>   my model s name = contact_model,
>   my table = contacts and group_contacts where contacts.gid = group_contacts.gid

and you have to mention specific UID (user id) before update your data.

if I run it, there are no error, but I can't modify the data.
can anyone of you help me?

Comment: are you getting values for $cid, $name, $email, $phone, $cbo_list, $uid in your model ?

Comment: akhil : yes, but not for $cid. i just get "1". what should i do to get the real id from contacts?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are wrong:

```
$this -> contact_model -> update($this -> input -> post('name'), $this -> input -> post('email'), $this -> input -> post('phone'), $this -> input -> post('cbo_list'), $this -> session -> userdata('uid'));
```

Move the UID to the first parameter position

```
$this -> contact_model -> update($this -> session -> userdata('uid'), $this -> input -> post('name'), $this -> input -> post('email'), $this -> input -> post('phone'), $this -> input -> post('cbo_list'));
```

Alternatively, change your function from:

```
public function update($cid, $name, $email, $phone, $cbo_list)
```

to

```
public function update($name, $email, $phone, $cbo_list, $cid)
```

Comment: thats correct, the parameters aren't in sync with the function called.

Comment: thank you, but still cant working. i hve tried ur suggestions, but no change.
now im making some errors in my program, n now i know where my false is.
Error msg :

> UPDATE `contacts` SET `name` = 'asdasdas', `email` = 'esterc234@yahoo.com', `phone` = '085777789900', `gid` = '1' WHERE `uid` = '1' AND `aaaa` = '1' 

aaaa means cid, my error is cannot take the value of cid, 
should i use uri segment to grab the value? or any suggest for it?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the uid. I presumed you were.

Comment: jbc : yes, i cant get my $cid's value.

Comment: I need clarity, please. What is $cid? is it uid from $this -> session -> userdata('uid') or something else?

Comment: While I chew on that... assume $cid is a URI var like: www.example.com/site/1304 (1304 being our desired $cid). Pass it into public function update_contact() like this: $cid = $this->uri->segment(2);

Next modify your update call to this
 $this -> contact_model -> update($cid, $this -> input -> post('email'), $this -> input -> post('phone'), $this -> input -> post('cbo_list'));

Comment: jbc : Yes, u're right, cid is uri segment (3) [site/update/123141]. cid = id for contacts table too, it's primary key. the contents of contacts are cid, name, email, phone, gid (group id) and uid(user id). uid can get from session. i tried to use uri segment, but useless. the feedback still "1". how can i update data if i can't mention the cid?

Comment: Can you update your question with any changes you've made? There were some major changes from my original answer and our comments so far. I would like to get a better grasp of the code your are working with

Comment: JBC : first, thank for your answers, you are very helpful. this is my first time to use MVC, so im beginner with CI. About your first answer, u are correct, i just wrong to put the parameters. after i fixed it, i still can't update my data. i just realized that my false was i can't get cid's value. so, my question now, how do i can get the value of cid (the primary key of table) ?

Comment: Without seeing some sample data and/or what you've attempted so far, I don't have much else right now. A suggestion, change the name of your update function:

public function update($cid, $name, $email, $phone, $cbo_list)
{ ...

update() us a codeigniter/DB function.

Comment: failed again. i hope i can upload the image, but i don't have enough reputation. here is the sample data. (cid, name,email, phone, gid, uid) => (23091203, markus, mark_us@gmail.com, 018293123912, 1, 1). when i try to change the name to ronald, error. <*UPDATE `contacts` SET `name` = 'ronald', `email` = 'mark_us@gmail.com', `phone` = '018293123912', `gid` = '1' WHERE `uid` = '1' AND `cid` = 0> the value is 0 not 23091203. what should i do?

Comment: hi JBC.. success now, haha.. i just add hidden input, n everything can work so well..  thanks for helping me :)